# Telling me that I need flask but I already have it?

Tags: python, pip

every time I try to run ./startup .sh, I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask', but I already did pip install flask multiple time!!! im using startup.sh script from https://github.com/malwaredllc/byob/tree/master/web-gui
and if I do pip list, it shows flask,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Linux then there is 2 version of python which comes with it.
If you have more then one then use

`pip3 install flask`

**or**

`python3 -m pip install flask`

Tell me if you still have problem